# How to create module tag output 'sub-loop'

Tags: add-on, php, module, parsing

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
{exp:my_tag my-param2="1" my-param2="2"}
    <li>{title}</li>
    <li><ul>
    {my_fields}
        <li>{field_label}: {field_value}</li>
    {/my_fields}
    </ul></li>
{/exp:my_tag}
```

Is it possible to do it with a simple TMPL->parse_variables() or should I put in place something more complex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `parse_variables` function handles this natively so there's really no need to complicate things unless you need some additional functionality.

The [template class documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#master-variables-array) includes some detailed instructions, but basically you just need to add a `my_fields` array to your main array of variable data.

```
$vars['title'] = 'My Title';

$vars['my_fields'] = array(
    array('field_label' => 'Foo', 'field_value' => 'Something'),
    array('field_label' => 'Bar', 'field_value' => 'Something else')
);

$output = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
```

Comment: Thanks Dom, I was stuck with the fact that I had to make a 3D array, but it works well.